# Math.acos gives me a different value than my calculator

Tags: ruby, math, trigonometry

In Ruby,

```
Math.acos(10/70) * 57.2958
```

should return approximately 80 degrees (according to my calculator).
However it is returning approximately 90 degrees. Why is that?

Comment: Use `10.quo(70)` instead of `10/70`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add decimal points, or Ruby will assume integer division:

```
irb(main):006:0> Math.acos(10/70) / Math::PI * 180
=> 90.0
irb(main):007:0> Math.acos(10.0/70) / Math::PI * 180
=> 81.78678929826181
```

If you just use `10/70`, this will round to 0, and you get `Math.acos(0)` instead of `Math.acos(0.14..)` which is what you want.

Comment: Thank you, that clears things up.